# Qt/SQL - Get column type and name from table without record

Tags: c++, sql, qt, types

Using `Qt`, I have to connect to a database and list column's types and names from a table. I have two constraints:

1 The database type must not be a problem (This has to work on `PostgreSQL`, `SQL Server`, `MySQL`, ...)

2 When I looked on the internet, I found solutions that work but only if there are one or more reocrd into the table. And I have to get column's type and name with or without record into this database.

I searched a lot on the internet but I didn't find any solutions.

I am looking for an answer in `Qt/C++` or using a query that can do that.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`QSqlDriver::record()` takes a table name and returns a `QSqlRecord`, from which you can fetch the fields using `QSqlRecord::field()`.

So, given a `QSqlDatabase` db,

1. fetch the driver with `db.driver()`,
2. fetch the list of tables with `db.tables()`,
3. fetch the a `QSqlRecord` for each table from `driver->record(tableName)`, and
4. fetch the number of fields with `record.count()` and the name and type with `record.field(x)`

Comment: Note: QSqlDatabase also has a [record](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#record) function, using that would simplify your solution (together with QSqlDatabase::tables of course)

Answer (score 2):

According to the previous answers, I make the implementation as below.It can work well, hope it can help you.

```
  {
      QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSLITE", "demo_conn"); //create a db connection
      QString strDBPath = "db_path";
      db.setDatabaseName(strDBPath); //set the db file
      QSqlRecord record = db.record("table_name"); //get the record of the certain table
      int n = record.count();
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        QString strField = record.fieldName(i);
      }
    }
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("demo_conn"); //remove the db connection
```

Comment: Please add some explanation besides the source code.

Comment: OK, I will add.

Answer (score 0):

Getting column names and types is a database-specific operation. But you can have a single C++ function that will use the correct sql query according to the `QSqlDriver` you currently use:

```
QStringlist getColumnNames()
{
    QString sql;

    if (db.driverName.contains("QOCI", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
         sql = ...
    }
    else if (db.driverName.contains("QPSQL", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
         sql = ...
    }
    else
    {
         qCritical() << "unsupported db";
         return QStringlist();
    }

    QSqlQuery res = db.exec(sql);
    ...
    // getting names from db-specific sql query results
}
```

Comment: I thought using ODBC driver for the connection in order to abstract databse type. But considered what you are saying, using ODBC driver is impossible isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any existing mechanism in Qt which allows that (though it might exist - maybe by using `QSqlTableModel`). If noone else knows of such a thing, I would just do the following:

1. Create data classes to store the information you require, e.g. a class `TableInfo` which stores a list of `ColumnInfo` objects which have a name and a type.
2. Create an interface e.g. `ITableInfoReader` which has a pure virtual `TableInfo* retrieveTableInfo( const QString& tableName )` method.
3. Create one subclass of `ITableInfoReader` for every database you want to support. This allows doing queries which are only supported on one or a subset of all databases.
4. Create a `TableInfoReaderFactory` class which allows creation of the appropriate `ITableInfoReader` subclass dependent on the used database

This allows you to have your main code independent from the database, by using only the `ITableInfoReader` interface.

Example:

---

Input:

- **database**: The QSqlDatabase which is used for executing queries
- **tableName**: The name of the table to retrieve information about

---

```
ITableInfoReader* tableInfoReader = 
    _tableInfoReaderFactory.createTableReader( database );

QList< ColumnInfo* > columnInfos = tableInfoReader->retrieveTableInfo( tableName );
foreach( ColumnInfo* columnInfo, columnInfos )
{
    qDebug() << columnInfo.name() << columnInfo.type(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You just have to call the `record` function from `QSqlDatabase`. You have an empty record but you can still read column types and names.